Proving Row Independence in Matrix Product Resulting from Linearly Independent Vectors and Permutations

Let's denote by $u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_n$ a set of linearly independent vectors. For each $i$ from $1$ to $n$, we define $\sigma_i$ as distinct permutations of the numbers $1$ to $n$. Construct matrix $A$ such that its $i$-th row is the transpose of $\sigma_i (\sigma_i^T)$, and matrix $B$ such that its $i$-th row is the transpose of $u_i (u_i^T)$. Given that the product of these matrices is $C = AB$, I am attempting to prove that the rows of $C$ are linearly independent.

My approach was to consider the broader property that the multiplication of two matrices comprised of linearly independent rows should result in a matrix with linearly independent rows. I thought to approach this by examining the equation $(AB)x = 0$ and leveraging the associative property of matrix multiplication to facilitate the proof
I seek guidance to refine my proof, especially in correctly applying the associative property in this context, and to understand how to handle edge cases such as when $n = 1$. Any insights or suggestions on proving the linear independence of the rows of $C$ or alternative approaches to this problem would be greatly appreciated.

One way to think about matrix multiplication is that,
$$
\def\qty#1{\left( #1 \right)}
C=AB = \begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12} & \cdots & A_{1n} \\
A_{21} & A_{22} & \cdots & A_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
A_{n1} & A_{n2} & \cdots & A_{nn} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
B_{1\bullet} \\
B_{2\bullet} \\
\vdots \\
B_{n\bullet}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11}B_{1\bullet} +A_{12}B_{2\bullet}+\cdots+ A_{1n}B_{n\bullet}\\
A_{21}B_{1\bullet} +A_{22}B_{2\bullet}+\cdots+ A_{2n}B_{n\bullet}\\
\vdots \\
A_{n1}B_{1\bullet} +A_{n2}B_{2\bullet}+\cdots+ A_{nn}B_{n\bullet}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
i.e. each row of matrix $C$ is a linear combination of the rows of matrix $B$
(row $i$ is denoted as $B_{i\bullet}$).
If the rows of matrix $C$ are not independent then we can find a linear combination of two or more rows with the property:
\begin{equation}
\sum_r a_r C_{r\bullet}=0  \tag{I} \label{I}
\end{equation}
where $a_r\neq 0$. Since,
$$
C_{r\bullet}=\sum_{i=1}^n A_{ri} B_{i\bullet}
$$
we can rewrite ($\ref{I}$) as,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \qty{\sum_r a_r A_{ri}} B_{i\bullet}=0
$$
The rows of $B$ are independent and so this is true only if,
$$
\sum_r a_r A_{ri}=0 \quad \text{for all $i$}
$$
We can rewrite this as the following system of equations:
$$
\eqalign{
A_{11}a_1+A_{21}a_2&+\ldots+A_{n1}a_n& =0 \\
A_{12}a_1+A_{22}a_2&+\ldots+A_{n2}a_n& =0 \\
&\vdots & \\
A_{1n}a_1+A_{2n}a_2&+\ldots+A_{nn}a_n& =0 
}
$$
which is equivalent to $A^T a =0$ or $a^TA=0$. Since,
$$
a^T A = a_1 A_{1\bullet}+a_2 A_{2\bullet}+\ldots+a_n A_{n\bullet}=0
$$
and the rows of matrix $A$ are independent this holds only if
$a_1=a_2=\ldots=a_n=0$. So we conclude that the rows of matrix $C$ are independent.
